# Update Postgresql table using rank()

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to update a column (`pop_1_rank`) in a postgresql table with the results from a `rank()` like so:

```
UPDATE database_final_form_merge
SET    
    pop_1_rank = r.rnk
FROM (
    SELECT pop_1, RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY pop_1 DESC) FROM database_final_form_merge WHERE territory_name != 'north'  AS rnk)r
```

The `SELECT` query by itself works fine, but I just can't get it to update correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is no `FROM` clause in the `SELECT`. How can this possibly work correctly?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Sorry...missed something as I was turning into "pseudocode"

Comment: For start your alias should be after the `RANK() OVER() as rnk` not after the `WHERE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I rather use the CTE notation.

```
WITH cte as (
     SELECT pop_1, 
            RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY pop_1 DESC) AS rnk
     FROM database_final_form_merge 
     WHERE territory_name <> 'north'  
)
UPDATE database_final_form_merge 
SET pop_1_rank = cte.rnk
FROM cte
WHERE database_final_form_merge.pop_1 = cte.pop_1
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Postgres updates *tables* not subqueries.  So, you can `join` back to the table:

```
UPDATE database_final_form_merge
    SET    pop_1_rank = r.rnk
    FROM (SELECT pop_1, RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY pop_1 DESC) as rnk
          FROM database_final_form_merge
          WHERE territory_name <> 'north'
         ) r
    WHERE database_final_form_merge.pop_1 = r.pop_1;
```

In addition:

- The column alias goes by the column name.
- This assumes that `pop_1` is the id connecting the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing WHERE on UPDATE query, because when doing UPDATE ... FROM you're basically doing joins.

So you need to select primary key and then match on primary key to update just the columns are computing rank over.

Comment: Okay...a bit new to this, can you give me a little direction?